# JavaScript SlideShow - Crossfading effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

I have a JavaScript SlideShow and I want to remove the "flash" effect when image change, and add crossfading effect instead. I have found a lot of solutions but nothing works I don't know why :-( ...

I have pasted my code here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/nanoupi42/xu06jdb2/1/

HTML :

```
<div class="slideshow-container hidden__M__Device">

        <div class="mySlides fades">

          <img src="http://images7.alphacoders.com/338/338687.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">

        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fades">

          <img src="https://www.usine-digitale.fr/mediatheque/9/3/5/000729539/viveport-infinity.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">

        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fades">

          <img src="https://www.philosophytalk.org/sites/default/files/o-INFINITY-facebook.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="dots_container hidden__M__Device">

        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>

        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>

        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>

      </div>
```

CSS :

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1082px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.mySlides{
  display: none;
}

.mySlides > img {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  /* top:-154px; */
}

.dots_container{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 230px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 81.5%;
}

.dot {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.fades {
  -webkit-animation-name: fades;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fades;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fades {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fades {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

JavaScript :

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
setInterval(plusSlides, 2000, 1); // call plusSlider, with 1 as parameter
```

As you can see, when picture change there is a sort of "flash" effect. I want to remove it and add crossfading effect like this https://cobwwweb.com/simple-looping-crossfade-image-slideshow. Do you have an idea how can I do this ?

Thank so much.

Nanou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the css animation on class `fades`.
The Keyframes work with `opacity`, you could change them to work with `translateX` on `transform` property.

```css
@keyframes fades {
  from {transform: translateX(-100%)}
  to {transform: translateX(0%)}
}
```

If you need help with animations there is [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) or ofc every documentation about the css animation properties.

Comment: Thanks so much ! I found a solution to add a good transition with your code :-)